# IN Clause with NULL or IS NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, conditional-statements, in-clause

Postgres is the database

Can I use a NULL value for a IN clause? example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id_field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', NULL)
```

I want to limit to these four values.

I have tried the above statement and it doesn't work, well it executes but doesn't add the records with NULL id_fields.

I have also tried to add a OR condition but this just make the query run and run with no end in sight.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE other_condition = bar
AND another_condition = foo
AND id_field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
OR id_field IS NULL
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: An `in` statement will be parsed identically to `field=val1 or field=val2 or field=val3`. Putting a null in there will boil down to `field=null` which won't work.

Comment: the 2nd query should be right. what other things are in your `where` clause?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, updated to reflect the query with more conditions

Answer (score 182, accepted):

> An `in` statement will be parsed identically to `field=val1 or field=val2 or field=val3`. Putting a null in there will boil down to `field=null` which won't work.

([Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362112/in-clause-with-null-or-is-null#comment7448343_6362112) by [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b))

I would do this for clairity

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE 
(id_field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') OR id_field IS NULL)
```

Comment: Ahh that did it, thanks! So wrapping the fields adds both conditions to the WHERE clause? Just for clarification

Comment: @Phill - it was an order of operations problem.

Answer (score 33):

Your query fails due to [**operator precedence**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). `AND` binds before `OR`!
You need a pair of parentheses, which is not a matter of "clarity", but pure *logic necessity*.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_name
WHERE  other_condition = bar
AND    another_condition = foo
AND   (id_field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') OR id_field IS NULL);
```

The added parentheses prevent `AND` binding before `OR`. If there were no other `WHERE` conditions (no `AND`) you would not need additional parentheses. The accepted answer is misleading in this respect.

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE coalesce(id_field,'unik_null_value') 
IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'unik_null_value')
```

So that you eliminate the null from the check. Given a null value in id_field, the coalesce function would instead of null return 'unik_null_value', and by adding 'unik_null_value to the IN-list, the query would return posts where id_field is value1-3 or null.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful to future readers. How does your code help solve the issue?

Comment: From documentation: The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value in a list.
So when id_field is null then 'unik_null_value' would be returned and query return the correct record.

Answer (score 16):

The question as answered by Daniel is perfctly fine. I wanted to leave a note regarding NULLS. We should be carefull about using NOT IN operator when a column contains NULL values. You won't get any output if your column contains NULL values and you are using the NOT IN operator. This is how it's explained over here [http://www.oraclebin.com/2013/01/beware-of-nulls.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229070855/http://www.oraclebin.com/2013/01/beware-of-nulls.html) , a very good article which I came across and thought of sharing it.

Comment: Not sure how many of use have experienced this problem, but I had this exact issue mixing nulls and NOT IN operator and was scwabbling over it for the past two hour. THIS is the perp...

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: The like is alive now.

Answer (score 12):

**Note:** Since someone claimed that the external link is dead in **Sushant Butta's** answer I've posted the content here as a separate answer.

Beware of **NULLS**.

Today I came across a very strange behaviour of query while using IN and `NOT IN` operators. Actually I wanted to compare two tables and find out whether a value from `table b` existed in `table a` or not and find out its behavior if the column contains`null` values. So I just created an environment to test this behavior.

We will create table `table_a`.

```
SQL> create table table_a ( a number);
Table created.
```

We will create table `table_b`.

```
SQL> create table table_b ( b number);
Table created.
```

Insert some values into `table_a`.

```
SQL> insert into table_a values (1);
1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values (2);
1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_a values (3);
1 row created.
```

Insert some values into `table_b`.

```
SQL> insert into table_b values(4);
1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_b values(3);
1 row created.
```

Now we will execute a query to check the existence of a value in `table_a` by checking its value from `table_b` using `IN` operator.

```
SQL> select * from table_a where a in (select * from table_b);
         A
----------
         3
```

Execute below query to check the non existence.

```
SQL> select * from table_a where a not in (select * from table_b);
         A
----------
         1
         2
```

The output came as expected. Now we will insert a `null` value in the table `table_b` and see how the above two queries behave.

```
SQL> insert into table_b values(null);
1 row created.

SQL> select * from table_a where a in (select * from table_b);
         A
----------
         3

SQL> select * from table_a where a not in (select * from table_b);

no rows selected
```

The first query behaved as expected but what happened to the second query? Why didn't we get any output, what should have happened? Is there any difference in the query? **No**.

The change is in the data of table `table_b`. We have introduced a `null` value in the table. But how come it's behaving like this? Let's split the two queries into `"AND"` and `"OR"` operator.

### First Query:

The first query will be handled internally something like this. So a `null` will not create a problem here as my first two operands will either evaluate to `true` or `false`. But my third operand `a = null` will neither evaluate to `true` nor `false`. It will evaluate to `null` only.

```
select * from table_a whara a = 3 or a = 4 or a = null;

a = 3  is either true or false
a = 4  is either true or false
a = null is null
```

### **Second Query:**

The second query will be handled as below. Since we are using an `"AND"` operator and anything other than `true` in any of the operand will not give me any output.

```
select * from table_a whara a <> 3 and a <> 4 and a <> null;

a <> 3 is either true or false
a <> 4 is either true or false
a <> null is null
```

So how do we handle this? We will pick all the `not null` values from table `table_b` while using `NOT IN` operator.

```
SQL> select * from table_a where a not in (select * from table_b where b is not null);

         A
----------
         1
         2
```

So always be careful about `NULL` values in the column while using `NOT IN` operator.

**Beware of NULL!!**

Comment: Excellent answer. I have just discovered the problem in my work. Very very strange behavior of Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is late to answer but could be useful for someone else
You can use sub-query and convert the null to 0

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN id_field IS NULL 
                THEN 0 
                ELSE id_field 
            END AS id_field
      FROM tbl_name) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.id_field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 0)
```

Comment: This is similar to Ove Halseth's answer using coalesce.

Answer (score 1):

EASY: This would give TRUE and null values:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE 
id_field IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') IS NOT FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Null` refers to an absence of data. `Null` is formally defined as a value that is unavailable, unassigned, unknown or inapplicable (OCA Oracle Database 12c, SQL Fundamentals I Exam Guide, p87).
So, you may not see records with columns containing null values when said columns are restricted using an "in" or "not in" clauses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're field is a numerical type, here is the solution I've used successfully.

(campaignid::text in ($campaignid) or (campaignid is null and 'null' in ($campaignid)))