# TSQL: NULL in the "IN" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a need to filter records where:

```
NotificationRead = 0 || NULL --> IF GetRead = 0
NotificationRead = 1 --> IF GetRead = 1
NotificationRead = 0 || 1 || NULL --> IF GetRead = NULL
```

Here is the query I am using for this:

```
DECLARE @GetRead BIT
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(20)

SET @GetRead = NULL

IF @GetRead = 0 SET @Query = '0,NULL'
ELSE IF @GetRead = 1 SET @Query = '1'
ELSE SET @Query = '0,1,NULL'

SELECT * FROM vwNotifications  WHERE NotificationRead IN (@Query)
```

The query above basically fails when I supply `NULL` in the `IN` clause.
I do know the reason why thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362112/in-clause-with-null-or-is-null).

But if I take an approach as suggested in that question's answer (using `NotificationRead IN (@Query) OR NotificationRead IS NULL`), I get all records where `NotificationRead = NULL` when I don't need them for example, when `@GetRead = 1`

Can you please point me to the right direction here?

Comment: You can't use `NULL` in `IN` clase because `NULL`s cannot be compared with other values/variables in the context of `SQL Server`. For exmaple, the following statement will return nothing: `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TEST] WHERE [TestColumn] IN (NULL)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the problem is that you are providing the values as strings.

```
1 IN (1, 2) -- true.
1 IN ('1, 2') -- false.
```

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM vwNotifications 
WHERE (@GetRead = 0 AND (NotificationRead = 0 OR NotificationRead IS NULL))
OR    (@GetRead = 1 AND NotificationRead = 1)
OR    (@GetRead IS NULL AND (NotificationRead IN (0, 1) OR 
                             NotificationRead IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 3):

Others may have a better way, but I would move your select into each of the 'if' statements, and modify accordingly.

```
IF @GetRead = 0
    SELECT * FROM vwNotifications WHERE NotificationRead IS NULL or NotificationRead = 0
ELSE IF @GetRead = 1 
    SELECT * FROM vwNotifications WHERE NotificationRead = 1
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM vwNotifications WHERE NotificationRead IS NULL or NotificationRead in 0, 1
```

Note:  Please don't actually use `SELECT *` in production code.  Name your columns.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Notify INT)
DECLARE @GetRead BIT
SET @GetRead = 0

INSERT INTO @T
        ( Notify )
VALUES  ( 0  -- Notify - int
          )

INSERT INTO @T
        ( Notify )
VALUES  ( 1  -- Notify - int
          )

INSERT INTO @T
        ( Notify )
VALUES  ( NULL  -- Notify - int
          )

SELECT *
FROM @t t
WHERE @GetRead IS NULL 
    OR (@GetRead = 0 AND (t.Notify =0 OR t.Notify IS NULL))
    OR (@getRead = 1 AND t.Notify = @GetRead)

SELECT *
FROM @t t
WHERE @GetRead IS NULL 
    OR ISNULL(t.notify, 0) = @GetRead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add SET ANSI NULLS OS top of query. When added NULL can usable IN (NULL) clause.

```
SET ANSI NULLS OFF
SELECT * ......
....
WHERE UserId IN (1, 2, NULL)
```