# mysql SELECT IF statement with OR

Tags: mysql, sql, select, if-statement

The following works - returns Y when chargeback equal to 1 else it defaults to N

```
IF(fd.charge_back = 1, 'Y', 'N') AS charge_back
```

however I cannot seem to get this one working?  Is the syntax valid

```
IF(compliment = ('set' OR 'Y' OR 1), 'Y', 'N') AS customer_compliment
```

Comment: What if you change your condition to `compliment IN ('set','Y','1')`

Comment: You might consider just not doing this in your query. This is formatting, not querying anymore. You get a clear true/false 1/0 in return which should do the trick. 

For example you could do: if(compliment) etc which cannot be done with a string like Y/N. 

Also Y/N is language agnostic while the boolean is not. So when translating to dutch for example you would have to convert Y/N again to J/N. 

In short: Maybe just don't do this unless you have a very good reason to do so or just have to take a cut-off solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback i agree boolean would be a better value to use.  However im working with existing data and not able to change all the values without further knock on effect on other parts.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Presumably this would work:

```
IF(compliment = 'set' OR compliment = 'Y' OR compliment = 1, 'Y', 'N') AS customer_compliment
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but does an `IN` clause work here? E.g. `IF(compliment IN('set','Y',1), 'Y', 'N') AS customer_compliment`?

Answer (score 18):

```
IF(compliment IN('set','Y',1), 'Y', 'N') AS customer_compliment
```

Will do the job as [Buttle Butkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631764/buttle-butkus) suggested.

Comment: This is a good shout for `VARCHAR` and `INT` values, but does not work with `null`.  [Cross-reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362216/6340496).