# Search page using 3 parameters

Tags: asp.net

I need to search training programs using 3 optional parameters (title, country, category). 
I am confused, how I can display all data when visitor doesn't filter the data and filter it when they send it as query string ?
(ex. resutls.aspx?title=title&country=usa&category=leaders)

how to implement this using sql server and asp.net (c#) ?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSourceID="srcTraining">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr>
                  <td><%#Eval("title") %></td>
                  <td><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> <%#Eval("country") %></td>
                  <td><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><%#Eval("days") %> days</td>
                  </tr>
              </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Look in sql first check that if the values are not null then Put the LIKE query for all otherwise dnt.

Comment: @KaushikKishore it's 3 parameters, so I should write all possible case? like if location is null, exclude it and search using others.. and so on

Comment: In my sql there is option for `OR` operation see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112029/mysql-select-if-statement-with-or/9112102#9112102

Comment: @KaushikKishore in this case when visitor doesn't use filtering, the data will not display anything because the search query doesn't match any OR

Comment: You're not understanding what i'm saying. Look like this. Your SQL query + if(Here Like Query.). It will be appended only there would be value.

Comment: @KaushikKishore thanks for you, please take a look to my answer, I solved the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this take long time from me but finally I find a way to do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT available_training.training_id, training.title
FROM            available_training INNER JOIN training 
ON 
    available_training.training_id = training.id
where
        (@location is null or available_training.country = @location) 
    and 
        (@category   IS NULL or category = @category)  
    and
        (@title is null or training.title like '%'+@title+'%');
```

hopefully, it will help someone else