# Oracle Selecting Columns with IN clause which includes NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

So I am comparing two Oracle databases by grabbing random rows in database A, and searching for these rows in database B based off their key columns. Then I compare the rows which are returned in java.

I am using the following query to find rows in database B using the key columns from database A:

```
select * from mytable 
Where (Key_Column_A,Key_Column_B,Key_Column_C) 
in (('1','A', 'cat'),('2','B', 'dog'),('3','C', ''));
```

This works just fine for the first two sets of keys, but the third key('3','C', '') does not work because there is a null value in the third column. Changing the statement to ('3','C', NULL) or changing the SQL to

```
select * from mytable 
Where (Key_Column_A,Key_Column_B,Key_Column_C) 
in ((('1','A', 'cat'),('2','B', 'dog'),('3','C', ''))
OR (Key_Column_A,Key_Column_B,Key_Column_C) IS NULL);
```

will not work either.

Is there a way to include a null column in an IN clause? And if not, is there a way to efficiently do the same thing? (My only solution currently is to create a check to make sure there are no nullable columns in my keys which would make this process rather unefficient and somewhat messy).

Comment: Are you generating this SELECT statement dynamically?

Comment: @BobJarvis yes I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it this way. I think it would work.

```
 select * from mytable 
  Where (NVL(Key_Column_A,''),NVL(Key_Column_B,''),NVL(Key_Column_C,'')) 
   in (('1','A', 'cat'),('2','B', 'dog'),('3','C', ''));
```

I am not sure about this `(Key_Column_A,Key_Column_B,Key_Column_C) IS NULL`. Wouldn't this imply that all of the columns (A,B,C) are NULL ?

Comment: NVL is a unknown command in my version of Oracle. That attempt was based on the answer I saw here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362112/in-clause-with-null-or-is-null

Comment: I don't know about your version. Use the equivalent and it would work. `Coalesce` for instance.

Comment: Btw, the thread you've shared is different from yours. It compares a value against a list. Here, you are comparing a list against a list.

Comment: Ahh my mistake. Adding NVL to every column removes the unknown command error. But this still doesn't seem to be working as it doesn't return any row for me when I am sure it exists.

Comment: is your `IN` statement generated by java ?

Comment: Yes, it is generated dynamically through java.

Comment: Is it possible to see the code that generated this : 
`('1','A', 'cat'),('2','B', 'dog'),('3','C', '')` ?

Comment: Why is that necessary? I am certain it is not an error with the way the SQL is generated. Does the SQL you originally posted actually work for you, or is it more of a theoretical solution?

Comment: Yes. It worked. Are you sure that you did not add spaces within the quotes or anything ? 
I am using a postgresql : 
`select case when ('A','B','') = (coalesce('A',''),coalesce('B',''), coalesce(NULL,'')) then 'Worked' else 'Did not' end`

Comment: Hmm here is a direct example of what is generated (only replaced column names and table):                                                                                                                select * from schema.table Where (NVL(Col_A,''), NVL(Col_B,''), NVL(Col_C,''), NVL(Col_D,''), NVL(Col_E,'')) IN (('','1','C002340237A','8258','MK'));

Comment: An empty string is the same as null in Oracle, so `NVL(Key_Column_A,'')` is `NVL(Key_Column_A,null)`, which doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: @Alex Poole Right ! 
In that way, you can use `NVL(Key_Column_A,'''''')`  (which is not beautiful)

Comment: @AlexPoole AHH I think you have solved my problem. I need to replace the searched null value with a temporary value. Like NVL(Key_Column_A,'N') IN ('N')

Comment: @JoshKni8 You'll have to make sure also that the target search also gets the temporary value and not ''.