# Sqlalchemy how to filter column which contains both Null and integer values

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have table with a nullable column which contains both types of values Null (as default) and integer:

```
class Node(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "node"
    maintenance = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
```

The request is like this one:

```
maintenance = 1
node_list = Node.query.filter(Node.maintenance != maintenance).all()
```

I need to select all cells which contains `Null` or `0` values.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I need to select all cells which contains 'Null' or '0' values.

**Using `|` as the logical `OR`**

```
Node.query.filter((Node.maintenance == None) | (Node.maintenance == 0))
```

**Using `is_(None)`**

Or, to avoid using `== None` (because of linters)

```
Node.query.filter((Node.maintenance.is_(None)) | (Node.maintenance == 0))
```

**Using `or_`**

Or, this form

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
Node.query.filter(or_(Node.maintenance == None, Node.maintenance == 0))
```

**Using `in_`**

If are wondering if you can query using something akin to the `in` operator in SQL and Python, you're right you can do it in SQLAlchemy too, but unfortunately [**it doesn't work for `None/NULL` values**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362112/in-clause-with-null-or-is-null), but to illustrate we can see that

```
Node.query.filter(Node.maintenance.in_([0, 1]))
```

is equivalent to

```
Node.query.filter((Node.maintenance == 0) | (Node.maintenance == 1))
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Came here looking for an answer to weather `None` could be used in `in_` – +1.

Comment: can I query that Node.maintenance contains 12.
for example, 12, 123, 012 , 0812 this is ok.

Comment: how will this be if maintenance is a hybrid method?