# SQLAlchemy filter for None/NULL Value - WORKS - but how to have it in_ a list?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

I want to filter my data for `None` or in MySQL dialect `NULL` values in a column.

This is easily done by:

`db.query(models.Data).filter(models.Data.multiplier == None).all()`

Well, but I am building a kind of advanced filter & sort function. Therefore, I have a list with values I want to filter for, e.g.:

`[1,2,5]`

Filtering my data for this is easy, too:

`db.query(models.Data).filter(models.Data.multiplier.in_([1,2,5])).all()`

But now I also want to allow a `None` value in my list:

`[1,2,5,None]`

Filtering:

`db.query(models.Data).filter(models.Data.multiplier.in_([1,2,5,None])).all()`

However, all rows having `NULL` as value in the `multiplier` column are **NOT** returned. Why is the usage of `None` not working with the `in_` function? How to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NULL` [doesn't compare as equal to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362216/5320906), so

```
SELECT bar 
  FROM foo
  WHERE bar IN (1, 2, 3 , NULL)
```

will return rows where `bar` is `1` or `2` or `3` but not if `bar` is `NULL`.

Instead you need offer the `NULL` case as an alternative to the `IN` case.

```sql
SELECT bar FROM foo WHERE bar IN (1, 2, 3) OR bar IS NULL
```

or in SQLAlchemy terms

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

...

result = (session.query(Foo)
                 .filter(
                     sa.or_(
                         Foo.bar.in_([1, 2, 3]),
                         Foo.bar == None
                     )
                 )
)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make comparisons using `None` (to match `NULL`) using the [`is_()` column operator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.is_). To check that a column is not `NULL`, you can use `is_not`.

As in:

```py
result = Foo.filter(
    sa.or_(
        Foo.bar.in_([1,2,3]), 
        Foo.bar.is_(None)
    )
)
```

But yes, listen to snakecharmerb when you're filtering with in_.