# Postgres query for IN(NULL, 'test') does not work

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, postgres-10

When I wan't to match a column that has some certain string values or is null, I assumed I can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN (NULL, 'someTest', 'someOtherTest');
```

But it does not return the columns where `column_name` set set to NULL. Is this anywhere documented? Why does it not work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IN Clause with NULL or IS NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362112/in-clause-with-null-or-is-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare NULL values using `=` (which is what `IN` is doing).

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html)

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying “unknown”), not true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields null, as does 7 <> NULL

You need to add a check for NULL explicitly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (column_name IN ('someTest', 'someOtherTest') OR column_name IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

NULL and empty string (i.e ' ') both are considered different in Postgres, unlike Oracle.

The query can be modified as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (column_name IN ('someTest', 'someOtherTest', '', ' ') OR 
column_name IS NULL);
```